# error in flutter yaml expect font asset to be a string

Tags: flutter

I think its an indentation error but they seem fine
error message-
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Expected font asset [fonts/IndieFlower-Regular.ttf] ((YamlList)) to be a string.

```
  fonts:
    - family: IndieFlower
      fonts:
        - asset:  fonts/IndieFlower-Regular.ttf
```

Comment: Are you sure that the fonts are in just font/folder? Maybe you placed them into assets/fonts/..?

Comment: no its folder is in the build folder

Answer (score 0):

```
fonts:
    - family: 'IndieFlower'
      fonts:
        - asset:  fonts/IndieFlower-Regular.ttf
```